# Two tangent circles tangent with central circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

[See my problem on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/inlv0tn9y0)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL27N.png)

---

There is a circle with radius $R$ at center $(a_1, b_1)$ with the following equation

$(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=R^2$

Then a tangent circle with radius $r$ rotated by $\theta_0$ would have the following coordinates.

$a_2 = (R+r)cos(\theta_0)+a_1$

$b_2 = (R+r)sin(\theta_0)+b_1$

But what would be the coordinates for third circle with same radius $r$ that is tangent to both circles?

---

**What  i have tried**

let $t$ be the angle from central circle to the arc that ends on two tangent points. (sorry for bad english)

$t= \arcsin(\frac{2r}{R+r})+\theta_0$

the coordinates for third tangent circle with radius $r$ would be

$a_3 = (R+r)cos(t)+a_1$

$b_3 = (R+r)sin(t)+b_1$

---

**Problem**

Although the third circle (green) is tangent to central circle but its not tangent to the other circle (blue). what did i do wrong?

Also i get undefined values if $r$ is bigger than some value.

[See my problem on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/inlv0tn9y0)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL27N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You computed the angle $t$ incorrectly. Specifically, it should be (why?)
$$t = \theta_0 \pm 2\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{R+r}\right).$$

Comment: Oh. I thought when two circles are tangent then the distance between their center would be sum of their radius, in this case 2r. Now i can see why `2arcsin(r/(R+r))` works but i dont know why `arcsin(2r/(R+r))` doesn't work

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Try to find the angle opposite to the base of an isosceles triangles with the side lengths $R+r$, $R+r$ and $2r$. You would realize why the given formula works. For example, if $R=r$ then this angle should be $\pi/3$. What would your formula compute?

Comment: Thanks, my formula calculates $\pi/2$, I did a few experiments and i realized my mistake. I cant explain it well but i have it in my head . you know :)